# Replace child element with another element if it does not fit into parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed width. Inside it there are three buttons. The issue is that if these buttons are too long they don't fit into the div. What I want is to replace the last button (or two buttons if they are both too long) with small button. It should look like this: 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="listTags">
 <a href="#" class="btn">Sport</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn">Football</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn">Wolverhampton</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn" style="display:none">•••</a>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq9reaju/).

Comment: CSS cannot decide that, you need to explicitly define it else you need to use JS

Comment: Yes, I know. But doesn't know how to implement it (((

Comment: You can try it like this, get the width of the wrapper where you are holding buttons, sum up the width of your buttons inside, if it exceeds wrapper width than show the last button else keep the last button hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that will work, assuming jquery is being included:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listTags">
  <a id="one" href="#" class="btn">Sport</a>
  <a id="two" href="#" class="btn">Football</a>
  <a id="three" href="#" class="btn">Wolverhampton</a>
  <a id="four" href="#" style="display:none" class="btn">...</a>
</div>
<script>
var containerWidth = $(".listTags").width();
var one = $("#one").outerWidth();
var two = $("#two").outerWidth();
var three = $("#three").outerWidth();

if (one + two + three > containerWidth) {
    $("#three").hide();
    $("#four").show();
}
</script>
```

And here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsLa5pt9/

Answer (score 0):

The JS that I added was:

```
$(function() {
  var width = 0;
  $(".btn").each(function() { //searches for all elements with class "btn"
    width += ($(this).width() + 7); //+7 comes from padding
  });
  if (width > $('.listTags').width()) {
    $('.listTags').children().last().text("..."); //changes last child to ...
  }
})
```

And the comments explain what is going on. I think this is what you were aiming for, and here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nq9reaju/5/).